# Position absolute floating outside position relative in Chrome

Tags: css

I have a table with two cells and a span inside the right cell. I want the span to be positioned to the left end of the row, so I used these styles:

```
span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
tr {
    position: relative;
}
```

In Firefox it works well as seen here:

[image]

However, Chrome ignores the position:relative and the span floats outside the table:

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9wa2sruu/

Thank you so much in advance. :)

Comment: Oh...tables and positioning...always fun.

Comment: there you go: https://jsfiddle.net/9wa2sruu/10/

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for marking it as duplicate, I searched for similar questions but for some reason I didn't find that one. So `transform: scale(1,1);`? Oh, CSS, sometimes you kill me... @_@

Comment: @NabeelKhan Thank you, but I want the span to be positioned relative to the row, not to the cell. Also, I can't alter the structure of the table, it must be with CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

cant you just do it this way?

```
tr, td {
  position: relative;
}
```

and html:

```
<tr>
  <td><span></span></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9wa2sruu/9/

Comment: I can't move the span to the first cell because sometimes, depending on the variable chosen by the user, the first cell is removed. Due to limitations of the platform I must respect that structure and use only CSS.

Comment: you need to give a div around span and make it absolute https://jsfiddle.net/9wa2sruu/10/